# How to create a pop up dialog/layout without button pressed in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is my code, after `if` statement I want to show a dialog in my `else` statement. The layout is given below.

```
   else{
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder=new     AlertDialog.Builder(IS_Quiz.this);
View mView= LayoutInflater.from(IS_Quiz.this).inflate(R.layout.quiz_dialog,null);
                Button mbutton=(Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.SameSubject);
                Button mbutton2=(Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.AnotherSubject);
                mbutton.setText("Try Another "+subNameQuiz+" Quiz");
                TextView mtext=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.correctcount);
                mtext.setText(mScore);
                TextView mtext1=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.incorrectcount);
                mtext1.setText(incorrect);
                TextView mtext2=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.skippedcount);
                mtext2.setText(skipped);

mBuilder.setView(mView);
                  mBuilder.show();

            }
```

that is my java code for IS_QUIZ

```
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/correct"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/correct"
    android:text="0"

    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Skipped:    "
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
   android:id="@+id/Skipped"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Skipped"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Skipped"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/skippedcount"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Incorrect:    "
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/incorrect"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/incorrect"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/incorrect"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/incorrectcount"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/correct"
    android:background="#32996c"
    android:text="Try Another Same Subject Quiz"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClickSame"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/SameSubject"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Try Quiz From Another Subject"
      android:layout_below="@+id/SameSubject"
    android:background="#32996c"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClickAnother"
    android:id="@+id/AnotherSubject"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to Home Page"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnotherSubject"
    android:background="#32996c"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClickHome"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/GoHome"/>
```

How to create a pop up dialog/layout without button pressed in Android? This is the layout for dialog i want this layout to show as a popup. I want it without key press after else statement.

Comment: I dont understand can you post na image of your dialog?

Comment: Please post the error that you're facing along with your full xml code.

Comment: Am not getting anything . App stop working .

Comment: there is an activity. In which there is if else. if if condition is not true then the else part show popup the dialogue.. the dialog layout code is given above.. and else part is also given where i want to call this popup layout.

Comment: Place the Alertdialog outside the else statement and only add mBuilder.show(); within the else statement.